# Here-document comment of "expr" built-in Unix command creates weird behavior

Tags: shell

This really puzzles me. The following code gives me the error 'expr: syntax error' when I try to do multi-line comment using here document

```
<<EOF
echo "Sum is: `expr $1 + $2`"
EOF
```

Even if I explicitly comment out the line containing the expr using "#", the error message would still exist

```
<<EOF
#echo "Sum is: `expr $1 + $2`"
EOF
```

And I observed that this happens only when I supply the 2nd operand to the expr as variable. If I hardcode it to a numeric value then the error message would disappear, that is

```
<<EOF
echo "Sum is: `expr $1 + 2`"   # expr's second argument numeric value is hard coded, no error now
EOF
```

Could anyone enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here documents are processed in the same way that other text is processed in the shell. That is, variables are expanded, and commands in backticks are executed.

You can control this behaviour by putting different kinds of quotes around the `EOF`. In your case you probably want single quotes:

```
<<'EOF'
echo "Sum is: `expr $1 + $2`"
EOF
```

That will stop the shell doing anything "clever" with your text.

Answer (score 0):

That are a couple of errors in your code.  Here documents is a [type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents).

You should not use an echo inside a here document. cat the here document or use a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) and the echoed it.

This example will works:

```
cat <<EOF                                                                                                                                  
Sum is: `expr $1 + $2`                                                                                                                     
EOF
```

Comment: The OP is using the document for a comment. He can put whatever he wants in there, and having it print to screen when the code is run is probably not useful.